# How to stage data for Google Charts in Symfony?

Tags: javascript, symfony, google-visualization

I have been stuck on this for some time now:

In my Symfony application I want to retrieve some data from the database and build a Google Chart with it. It seems to me, though, that I cannot produce the JSON data in the format required.

In a first step, I want to replicate this [example provided by Google](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example), but with some (VERY basic) data of my own. (I want to display "manufacturer and item count instead of toppings and slices").

Here is my code for producing the chart in my TWIG template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);  

// Callback that creates and populates a data table,
// instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
// draws it.
function drawChart() {

/*    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "{{ path('my_data_collector_service') }}",
        dataType:"json",
        async: false
    }).responseText;*/

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Provider');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Items');
    data.addRows({{ jsonData|raw }});

    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'Products by Provider',
        'width':400,
        'height':300};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

This is what the JSON data looks like in the source code of the page generated:

```
data.addRows([{"name":"Apple","items":"2"},{"name":"LG Electronics","items":"1"}]);
```

Compared to the original code example, I appear to have an associative array structure, plus a lot of quotes surrounding all my element names and values.

**What do I have to change so that the Google Chart API can work with my data? What is a possible different best practice to generate such data?**

Here ist the code I use to generate the JSON data for reference:

```
class DataCollectorController extends Controller
{

    protected  $entityManager;

    public function __construct($entityManager) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function productsAction()
    {
        $encoders = array(new JsonEncoder());
        $normalizers = array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer());

        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

        $em = $this->entityManager;
        $query = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT prov.name, count(prod.id) as items
            FROM MyBundle:Product prod
            JOIN prod.provider prov
            GROUP BY prov.name'
        );

        $data = $serializer->serialize($query->getResult(), 'json');

        $response = new Response();
        $response->setContent($data);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return $response;

    }
}
```

Comment: The easiest approach here is *probably* to convert the query results into a non-associative array, and either set whatever flags are necessary in the json encoder to parse numbers appropriately or manually parse your data as numbers before passing the data to the converter.  I'm not familiar with Symfony's tools, but I could show you how it's done in plain PHP if that would help.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking, but I couldn't find anything on it yet. So any help with that type of conversion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got things working by adding this little bit to my Data CollectorController:

```
$res = $query->getResult();

foreach ($res as $val)
{
   $data[] = array($val['name'], (int) $val['items']);
}
```

This could almost also be achieved by simply running

```
foreach ($res as $val)
{
   $data[] = array_values($val);
}
```

But that way there is one problem left in that the number values are still enclosed in quotes.

The full class now looks like this:

```
class DataCollectorController extends Controller
{

    protected  $entityManager;

    public function __construct($entityManager) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function productsAction()
    {
        $encoders = array(new JsonEncoder());
        $normalizers = array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer());

        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

        $em = $this->entityManager;

        $query = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT prov.name, count(prod.id) as items
            FROM VSJourneyroWebBundle:Product prod
            JOIN prod.provider prov
            GROUP BY prov.name'
        );

        $res = $query->getResult();

        foreach ($res as $val)
        {
            $data[] = array($val['name'], (int) $val['items']);
        }

        $data = $serializer->serialize($data, 'json');

        $response = new Response();
        $response->setContent($data);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return $response;

    }
}
```

It is working, but it doesn't really feel "elegant" iterating over each bit of the result object. Especially the bit about casting the 'items' value. **Any suggestions for further improvements are still welcome.**

Comment: Check the documentation for the JSON serializer to see if it has an option to handle the type conversion.  The base PHP `json_encode` function supports doing this (via the `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` option), so I would be surprised if symfony's custom encoder does not.

Comment: I did not find the documentation of the Symfony Serializer component to be "revealing" in that regard. There is an option to use the very function you mentioned as part of the TWIG JSON encoder, though: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/json_encode.html. Which does not help in my case, however, as I am already returning a JSON-encoded array and would thus require some other adaptations.

Comment: Try replacing `$data = $serializer->serialize($data, 'json');` with `$data = json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`; if you don't have base json functions functionality disabled, it should work.